# in a forEach closure loop with two iteration variables, what does each variable represent?

Tags: ios, swift, loops

I'm learning Swift and trying to make sense of this forEach loop. I fully understand the single iteration loop:

```
stackVC.forEach { i in
    // do something
}
```

whereby for each iteration (i) in the loop, do something is executed. But in the case below, what is "i" and what is "j"? For context, stackVC is an array of UIViewController's that are being put together to go into a container view controller.

```
    stackVC.enumerated().forEach { i, j in
        let pageViewController = UIViewController()
        j.view.frame = pageViewController.view.bounds
        j.view.autoresizingMask = [
            .flexibleWidth,
            .flexibleHeight
        ]
        pageViewController.addChildViewController(j)
        pageViewController.view.addSubview(j.view)
        j.didMove(toParentViewController: pageViewController)
        stackPageVC.append(pageViewController)
    }
```

Comment: [enumerated()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated): Returns a sequence of pairs (n, x), where n represents a consecutive integer starting at zero, and x represents an element of the sequence.

Comment: You should always try to google your issue, or look up the documentation prior to posting here. In this case, simply option clicking on `enumerated` in Xcode would have showed you the API documentation for it, which would explain everything you're asking here

Comment: Easy for someone who has worked with Swift for a number of years to say. For a newbie, drawing that conclusion with a "simple Google search" would have been close to impossible. Lighten up a bit.

Comment: @thismeanswar How do you think any of us got into Swift? We googled for information. We stand on the shoulders of giants before us.

Comment: People like you definitely don't make it easier. When people post "obvious" questions, don't assume that person didn't Google the f**k out of it first. Google spits out a lot of garbage. And the entire time I'm searching forEach and completely missed the enumeration aspect of it. After an hour, I came on here. Zomg question wasn't supAr advanced.

Comment: @thismeanswar: What you could to is to start with `stackVC.enumerated().forEach { i, j in print(i, j) }` – From the output you get an  idea what i and j are, and if you  click on them in Xcode then the Quick help inspector shows the type.

Comment: @thismeanswar people like them also make it easier.

Comment: @MartinR excellent idea, to print to console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using enumerated.forEach you get the `offset` and the element.

Note, as per Martin’s comment. The offset is different from the index and so may not necessarily be the actual index.

Comment: `n` is actually called *offset,* not index, perhaps to emphasize that it can be different from a collection index (e.g. for array slices or strings).

Comment: You first said index and changed it to offset, even with a 47k reputation. Yet, people like Alex berate me for asking such an obvious question. Let this be a lesson to some. Thanks for the answer! Makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Also `enumerated()` works with arbitrary *sequences,* where the elements are not indexed.

Comment: @thismeanswar we’re all still learning here :-) sorry you’ve had bad experiences. I know I get them myself too. I am also guilty of giving them out.